# Locking just one element of a list. Is this the right way?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, concurrency, locking, mutex

I have a number of threads; some of them share an object; others share another one, while these objects are in a list (Dictionary) shared by all of the threads.

In other words, there is a list of objects, which is shared by all of the threads, though each one of them is using just one object of this list.

I'm not having problems with concurrency by locking the main list in this way:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private static List_of_objects list_of_objects;

    private static object var = new object();

    private static bool list_is_being_used = false;

    public void Main()
    {
        lock (var)
        {
            while(list_is_being_used)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(var);
            }

            list_is_being_used = true;

            // ... Do some things with an object of the list ...

            list_is_being_used = false;

            Monitor.Pulse(var);
        }
    }
}
```

Since each thread is going to use just one element of the list, I would like to lock that element alone, so just the threads using that element get locked while the rest of the threads using other elements don't.

I've thought something like this could do it:

```
public class MainClass
{
    private static List_of_objects list_of_objects;

    private static object var_x[] = new object [CONSTANT];  // I declare a mutex-variable for each element on the shared list
    ...

    private static bool element_x_is_being_used[] = [false,false,false,...];

    private ElementClass element; // I declare an object as a pointer to the element this thread is going to use. <---

    public void Main()
    {
        element = list_of_objects[1];

        ...

        lock (object var_x[1]) // I just want to lock this element of the list, not the whole list
        {
            while(element_1_is_being_used)
            {
                Monitor.Wait(object var_x[1]);
            }

            element_1_is_being_used = true;

            // ... Do some things with element 1 of the list ...

            element.set_whatever... // I change some values of the element

            element_1_is_being_used = false;

            Monitor.Pulse(object var_x[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, can I do it in this way?

I mean, Can I declare a non-static variable as a pointer to an element of a static list of elements assuming all of the process sharing a specific element will access it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object inside the collection is the same for every thread, even if the position of it within the list changes, so if you're going to use it to change properties of that object only, you'll be fine.

Just keep in mind that locking on `Collection[0]` does not mean "lock the first element within the collection", but "lock on the object *currently* at the first position within the collection".